# command mingw32-make -j 8 not working when trying to setup opencv and qt

Tags: windows, qt, cmake, mingw

I'm following the tutorial of "How to setup Qt and openCV on Windows" and right now I'm trying to do the commands

```
 mingw32-make -j 8
 mingw32-make install
```

but I get this error everytime I'm trying to do the first command, I get this error:

```
D:/qt/Tools/mingw1120_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: i386 architecture of input file `CMakeFiles\opencv_core.dir/objects.a(vs_version.rc.obj)' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make[2]: *** [modules\core\CMakeFiles\opencv_core.dir\build.make:1920: bin/libopencv_core460.dll] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:1806: modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:165: all] Error 2
```

I searched about how to fix the error, I tried changine the settings, reinstalling the folder the cmake and the opencv but nothing worked. can someone help me with it? thanks

Comment: You can not mix 32 and 64bit libraries.

Comment: Smells like you have **manually** specified **compilers** and/or `rc` tool, and these specifications are incompatible (mix 32bit and 64bit tools). How exactly have you configured the project (when run `cmake`)? Please, update your question post and include that information into it.